# Creating Jquery sliding menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Want to create jquery menu like on this website slide from left and when click on icon restores to its orignal position.

http://wittlingerorthodontics.com/default2.asp

only able to achieve this on jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/messi1987/tfASa/

```
$(function() {
// run the currently selected effect
function runEffect() {
// get effect type from
var selectedEffect = "slide";

// most effect types need no options passed by default
var options = {};
// run the effect
$( "#effect" ).effect( selectedEffect, options, 1000 );
};

// set effect from select menu value
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
runEffect();
return false;
});
});
```

whereas i want to make it slide in and on click to button/image slides back to orignal positon. New to jquery so do'nt get the helping content any where. Help me out to do this.
for complete understanding check the referenced website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this fiddle , i think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tfASa/19/) is what u want

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
         $(".ul_menu").toggleClass('show');
        if( $(".ul_menu").hasClass('show')){
        $(".ul_menu").show("slide",{direction: 'left'});
        }else{
          $(".ul_menu").hide("slide",{direction: 'left'});
        }
    });
    $('#button').mouseleave(function(){
        if($(".ul_menu").hasClass('show')){
           $(".ul_menu").hide("slide",{direction: 'left'});
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: almost the same thing but want to slide the runbutton/image at the same with menu. and only shown the runbutton/image on hide. Edit iff possible. Thanks

Comment: u need something in which u can clcik and open what u want, u can put your edit button back in list, and have another button or link clicking on which u can open your menu

Comment: but the menu is rolled back as the mouse hover is ended. i want it to staay there for few sec or until any other menu is not hoverd. thanks once again

Comment: then u can add mouseleave function for your ul menu , so it will hide, when u will mouseleave from opened list